# How to post to facebook page using phonegap plugin from mobile? Is there any other way to do?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, mobile, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, phonegap-plugins

How to post to facebook page using phonegap plugin from mobile?
 Is there any other way to do ?